# First IBAction trigger writes nil to array. Second trigger writes from first reference

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

When clicking an IBAction (`viewScheduleButtonTapped`) to read from Firestore db to array it returns 'nil'. I have to click a second time for it to write data to array. However, the data written is from the first (IBAction click) Firestore document reference selected. (a pickerview selects the Firestore document reference).

Print from first trigger

> scheduleIDOutput is test2 []

Print from second trigger

> scheduleIDOutput is test3 ["[[\"13\", \"13\", \"13\", \"13\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\"]]"]"

But this is the data from document "test2"

Here is the code (removed tableview code as it didn't do anything yet)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewScheduleViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextfield: UITextField!


    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

    var startHourArray: [String] = []
    var stopHourArray: [String] = []

    var startHourBreakArray: [String] = []
    var stopHourBreakArray: [String] = []

    var weekdayArray = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

    var scheduleIDOutput: String? = ""
    var scheduleStartDateOutput: Double? = nil


    //PickerView setup
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        myTextfield.text = pickerData[row]
        scheduleIDOutput = myTextfield.text
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myPicker = UIPickerView()
        myTextfield.inputView = myPicker


        // Ask db for a list of documents in collection
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("schedules").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    self.pickerData.append(document.documentID)
                }
            }

            print(self.pickerData)

        }

        myPicker.delegate = self
        myPicker.dataSource = self

    }

    @IBAction func viewScheduleButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

       // Fetch selected document from db
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("schedules").document("\(scheduleIDOutput ?? "")")

        docRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in

            guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
            let data = docSnapshot.data()

            let startHourInput = data["starttime"] as? String ?? ""
            let stopHourInput = data["stoptime"] as? String ?? ""

            let startHourBreakInput = data["startbreak"] as? String ?? ""
            let stopHourBreakInput = data["stopbreak"] as? String ?? ""

            let scheduleStartDateInput = data["schedulestartdate"] as? Int

            let viewSchedule = Schedule(scheduleStartDate: scheduleStartDateInput!, scheduleStartTime: startHourInput, scheduleStopTime: stopHourInput, scheduleStartBreak: startHourBreakInput, scheduleStopBreak: stopHourBreakInput)

            self.startHourArray = [viewSchedule.scheduleStartTime]
            self.stopHourArray = [viewSchedule.scheduleStopTime]

            self.startHourBreakArray = [viewSchedule.scheduleStartBreak]
            self.stopHourBreakArray = [viewSchedule.scheduleStopBreak]


        }


     print("scheduleIDOutput is \(scheduleIDOutput  ?? "empty") \(startHourArray)")

}
}
```

Comment: The `getDocument()` function is asynchronous - meaning the closure is executed when a result is returned. So your `print` is being called before the results come back. Put your `print` statement in the code block above it (after `self.stopHourBreakArray = [viewSchedule.scheduleStopBreak]`).

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot!